# Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

Im getting this error

```
error is here: Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.
```

in my firebase javascript function and I have no idea how to solve it . I found out that in typescript this error happens . But what does this error means in javascript ?

This is my function

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

import {
  deleteCollection,
  deleteQuery,
  deleteUserData,
} from "../utils/deletion";
export default functions.firestore
  .document("deletions/{userUid}")
  .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const { userUid } = context.params;
    const { uid } = userUid;
//dont forget to delete storage files
    try {
      await db.doc(`deletions/${userUid}/meinprofilsettings/${uid}`).delete();

        await deleteQuery(db, db.collection(`deletions/${userUid}/videos`).where("uid", "==", uid));
```

The line is the await deleteQuery...

The deleteQuery functions looks like this

```
async function deleteQuery(db, query, batchSize = 100) {
  const q = query.limit(batchSize);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, q, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}
async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();
  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done
    resolve();
    return;
  }
  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();
  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint.
> Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. If you want to ignore
> undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

This means that you have an ‘undefined’ value in your list. Firebase does not support undefined values in your list, check your list and see if something is `undefined`.  You can avoid this by using `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.  Here is an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin";
```

Then just need to have something like this:

```
const db = firestore.firestore(); 
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a filter to achieve this. I had no field as 'discount' in firestore documents

```
const activeSubscriptionsSnapshot = await db.collection("subscriptions");
.where("status", "==", "ACTIVE")
.get();
const subscriptionsWithoutDiscount = activeSubscriptionsSnapshot.docs
.filter((doc) => !("discount" in doc.data()));`
```